# Formula to calculate total of column where cells contain a value, multiplied by corresponding cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm sure it's very simple but I need a formula that will calculate everything in column B (if there is a figure there) multiplied by their corresponding cell in column A multiplied by 0.1

```
Column A        Column B    
250              1    
350       
450              2
```

Comment: After multiplying A2*B2*0.1, A3*B3*0.1... do you want to sum the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column C if you only need the product of each Row, and write the following formula:

`=IF(B2="","",A2*B2*0.1)`
Assuming your Data start in A2 and you can drag it down

If you want the Sum of the result without calculating each product you can use:
`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4)*(B2:B4)*0.1)`
A2:A4 is the Data reference of Column A
B2:B4 is the Data reference of Column B
0.1 the constant

`Sumproduct` will calculate the product of each set (A,B,0.1) and sum the result